# from scipy.integrate import odeint returns error

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, runtime-error

I ran this command `from scipy.integrate import odeint` but I get the errors below. I am new to python. I have installed `scipy` and `numpy` but I don't have any idea what more is missing to run this. Please help.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    from scipy.integrate import odeint
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from .quadrature import *
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadrature.py", line 6, in <module>
    from scipy.special.orthogonal import p_roots
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 601, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the `Numpy` from the following link which has `Numpy+MKL` build linked to the Intel® Math Kernel Library.

link: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Comment: Thanks but I still get the same error don't know what's wrong ? I have installed scipy, numpy, pylab but no luck :|

Comment: start from scratch, use another python distribution - check out anaconda